# BackupPC RSync job timing out

Tags: linux, windows, backup, rsync

I have a BackupPC RSync job that is not completing on a new server. The job just times out after signal ALRM. I increased the time out to 288000, but it will still time out and doesn't appear to ever really start backing anything up at all as it will still be at 0 of 0 files, and never gets a Xfer PID like my backups that work.

Any ideas on where to look at what is causing this problem? What other information would be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beat my head against a wall on this for quite sometime trying to figure out why it was not working. Turns out I am just bad... I fat fingered the firewall rule I put on the Windows server that BackupPC was hitting and put the wrong IP (for my BackupPC server) in. I overlooked it about a half dozen times before I figured it out.